# Spivak: For any convex function $f$ on some open interval containing $a$, show that $f'_-(a) \leq f'_+(a)$. Why can't we show $f'_-(a) = f'_+(a)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Spivak, Chapter 11 Appendix, "Convexity and Concavity":

> *9. (a) For any function $f$, the right-hand derivative, $\lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$, is denoted $f'_+(a)$,
> the left-hand derivative is denoted by $f'_-(a)$. The proof of Theorem
> 1 actually shows that $f'_+(a)$ and $f'_-(a)$ always exist if $f$ is
> convex on some open interval containing $a$. Check this assertion, and
> also show that $f'_+(a)$ and $f'_-(a)$ are increasing, and that
> $f'_-(a) \leq f'_+(a)$.

Here is what Theorem 1 is

> Let $f$ be convex. If $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then the graph of
> $f$ lies above the tangent line through $(a,f(a))$, except at
> $(a,f(a))$. If $a<b$ and $f$ differentiable at $a$ and $b$ then
> $f'(a)<f'(b)$.

Since $f$ is convex, by definition of convexity on $[a, a+h_2]$, where $h_2>0$ we have for any $0<h_1<h_2$ that

$$\frac{f(a+h_1)-f(a)}{h_1}<\frac{f(a+h_2)-f(a)}{h_2}$$

Therefore $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ decreases as $h \to 0^+$.

But does it decrease indefinitely? No because it can be shown that for any $h<0$, $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ is a lower bound for the set $\{x: x=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}, h>0 \}$. The set therefore has an infimum.

It can be shown that this infimum is $f'(a)$.

Similarly it can be shown that the supremum of $\{x: x=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}, h<0 \}$ is $f'(a)$.

Note also that for any $h$, $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} \neq f'(a)$, because otherwise $f$ wouldn't be convex between $a$ and $a+h$.

Since for $h>0$ we have $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}>f'(a)$ and for $h<0$ we have $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}<f'(a)$ then $f'_-(a) \leq f'_+(a)$, which is what Spivak asked us to prove.

**What prevents us from concluding that $f'_-(a) = f'_+(a)$?**

If $f$ isn't differentiable this could be the case, but doesn't the existence of $f'(a)$ mean it is differentiable?

I am wondering because usually when Spivak asks for a result that isn't as general or strong as I expect it means I am missing some detail.

Comment: Nothing in 9a references $f'(a)$.  It just references the proof of theorem 1, so as you guessed, you cannot assume $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Take $f(x) = |x|$ at $x=0$ for example. Maybe add $x^2$ to keep match Spivak's notion of convexity.

Comment: If $f'(a)$ exists then the right & left derivatives must be the same.